# jQuery autocomplete - Slow Server vs Local

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-autocomplete

as per the heading I'm facing issues with performance only once deployed. Its an ASP.NET MVC5 site and is deployed on Azure. We are talking ms vs several seconds :/

I can prepare a video or whatever would assist in solving this issue.
No js errors are thrown sadly :/

Here is an image showing it working perfectly locally [image: Working]

Live, it eventually shows after like 7/8 seconds.. if not longer. 
Code incoming...

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

            $("#SerialSearch").autocomplete({
                autoFocus: true,
                //delay: 0,
                minLength: 2, // minimum length to trigger suggestions
                select: function(e, ui) { // define select handler

                    //alert(ui.item.value);
                    //hitting enter key on selected item works, mouse clicking after 609 on V609xxx will submit 609 sadly
                    //With this I override the problem
                    $('#SerialSearch').val(ui.item.value);
                    //alert('here');
                    $(this).parents('form').submit();
                },

                source: function (request, response) {
                    @*var modelDataJSON = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';*@
                    var check = @Html.Raw(val);
                    //var modelDataJSON = JSON.stringify(check);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Devices/DeviceSearch",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { Prefix: request.term, model: check },
                        success: function (data) {
                            //alert('success');
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.SerialNumber, value: item.SerialNumber };
                            }))

                        }
                    })
                }
                //messages: {
                //    noResults: "", results: ""
                //}
            });
        })
```

cshtml :

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Devices";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    //var val = Json.Encode(Model);
    //Using viewdata to load in mem entire device list
    var val = Json.Encode(@ViewData["FullDeviceList"]);
}

@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Get))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div class="form-horizontal">
  <hr />
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SerialSearch, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Please give us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Wow you guys are fast :) Coming right up

Comment: You should also be showing the code which fetches data, the data access layer code. Just a hunch, is your azure service/project and the SQL server/database in different regions?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is determine the source of the problem.
I assume you have a server side source for the auto-complete control and get your data via Ajax calls. On local (dev site?) the latency for the Ajax call will be minimal. On Azure, because the host is remote, I would expect the latency to increase. (Of course, not knowing your implementation, this is only speculation)

Comment: Yeah, will need to debug this more on monday. Just thinking its something silly as they are the same DB. Local instance of the web app, but azure db regardless of local vs remote.

Comment: To add to this, Im storing the devices on page load - Viewdata vs hitting the db each keypress,

Comment: You could use Glimpse to pinpoint the problem. (usage guide, azure included, here: [link](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/profile-and-debug-your-aspnet-mvc-app-with-glimpse#da) )